# How can I force redirect using > in csh to clobber existing file?

Tags: linux

OSTYPE=linux
OS_KERNEL_VERSION=3.10.0
csh

When I try to clobber an existing file using redirect ">" I get an error... "File exists."

```
% date > the.log
% echo $?
0
% date > the.log
the.log: File exists.
% echo $?
1
```

How can I simply force the clobber of "the.log" without getting the error ?

Update:
This appears to be happening on one server but not others.  So it's a server specific thing... some sort of config setting ?

Comment: `date >| the.log`

Comment: % date >| the.log                                                                                                                     
    gives... "Missing name for redirect."

Comment: sorry, that was for bash/ksh. For csh/tcsh: `date >! the.log`.
Haven't used csh for neons....

Answer (score 0):

In linux you cannot have two files with same name,once check using ls commadn,if you dont want error give % date > the.log 2>&1  for both error and sucess to fall to log file

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Harish for the reply.
But vgersh99 got it right (the 2nd time).  For csh, you need the '!'.  Something to do with a noclobber setting in the shell.